# Changing variables in multiple integral (commutative of convolution operation)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 1$, the Lebesgue measure is denoted by $dx=dx_1\dots dx_n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx$ stnads for $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x_1\dots x_n)dx_1\dots dx_n$.

I want to prove that convolution operation is commutative, i.e. $f\ast g=g\ast f$. More precisely, 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)g(x-y)dy
$$

This is a consequence of changing variables. But if i say $x-y=u$ then $(-1)^n dy=du$ and the result is

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x-y)g(y)dy=(-1)^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)g(x-y)dy
$$

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T: \mathbb {R}^n\to  \mathbb {R}^n$ is a nice smooth bijection with $\det J_T(x)\ne 0$ for all $x,$ then

$$\int_{ \mathbb {R}^n} f(x)\,dx = \int_{ \mathbb {R}^n} f(T(y))|\det J_T(y)|\,dy.$$

Comment: Where can i find the proof of this theorem. Can you suggest me a reference ?

Comment: Google "change of variables in R^n" and you should get some good hits.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *how* you're parameterizing the whole space. In the left hand side, your integrals are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. In the integrals on the right hand side, it's the opposite parameterization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am i right $$
\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}\dots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-y)g(y)dy=(-1)^n \int_{+ \infty}^{- \infty}\dots\int_{+ \infty}^{- \infty}f(y)g(x-y)dy
$$ Is the equality $$(-1)^n \int_{+ \infty}^{- \infty}\dots\int_{+ \infty}^{- \infty}f(y)g(x-y)dy= \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}\dots\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty}f(y)g(x-y)dy$$ true?

Comment: Yes that's right.